# what is the difference between the various versions of gcc?

Tags: gcc

When I go to gcc's web site https://gcc.gnu.org/, I see 3 current versions: 5.5, 7.2, and 6.4. Unfortunately, there's no explanation anywhere I could see of what the differences between the three might be. One would expect that 7.2 would be the most recent but that doesn't appear to be the case, as they are all relatively recent (in fact 5.5 is more recent than 7.2). Does anyone know what the differences are and why one might be preferable to the others?

thanks

Comment: On the right side in **Supported Releases** click on changes next to the version. 5.5 is not over there because it is not one of the last 3 major versions. It seems if you click on the version # on the left side you can see the information for 5.5 as well.

Comment: I think your are confusing the most recent version with the most recent to have had bug-fixes. `7.2` is the most recent version. Look at "changes" to see how it differs from the previous version.

Comment: If you click on any of those versions it takes you to a page which lists the changes introduced in that version. gcc-7 is the latest, but releasing a new version doesn't mean support for all earlier versions ends immediately.

Comment: Unfortunately, all these "answers" miss the point of the question: what, in a nutshell, are the main differences between the 3 paths - I won't call them versions since that seems to trigger an allergic reaction among some people. Is this the beginning of a "Berkeley vs System V"  rivalry? What is a newcomer to gcc to make of being presented with 3 "current" paths? Surely, someone can jump in with a short paragraph answer

Answer (score 2):

Major versions add new features. Minor versions fix bugs. If a bug is found in an earlier major version, a new minor version is released to fix it.